# Julia - Reshaping a 4D array into a matrix of matrices

Tags: arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, julia, reshape

I want to start from an array like
`A = zeros( nK , nK , m , m )`
and reshape it into an matrix of size `(nK,nK)` where each element is an `mxm` matrix.

I have tried the basis `reshape` function, `reshape(A , nK , nK )`, but it gives me

`DimensionMismatch("new dimensions (nK, nK) must be consistent with array size mxmxnKxnK")`

Comment: The first dimension in an array is the fastest moving i.e. the elements of `A[:,i,j,k]` are bunched together in memory. Therefore it makes sense to transform `A` into an `mxm` matrix of `nKxnK` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I think you can do it this:

```
julia> x = rand(1:10, 2, 4, 3, 3)
2×4×3×3 Array{Int64, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 9  5  4   1
 2  2  2  10

[:, :, 2, 1] =
 8  1  4  9
 9  5  5  8

...

julia> # With copy:

julia> [x[i, j, :, :] for i in axes(x, 1), j in axes(x, 2)]
2×4 Matrix{Matrix{Int64}}:
 [9 5 4; 8 2 6; 5 7 5]  [5 8 5; 1 6 1; 1 5 5]   [4 10 4; 4 3 10; 4 7 10]  [1 10 5; 9 2 5; 7 1 10]
 [2 7 1; 9 5 3; 7 1 7]  [2 3 9; 5 7 10; 4 1 4]  [2 1 2; 5 1 1; 1 2 4]     [10 1 3; 8 3 8; 9 10 2]

julia> # With views:

julia> [view(x, i, j, :, :) for i in axes(x, 1), j in axes(x, 2)]
2×4 Matrix{SubArray{Int64, 2, Array{Int64, 4}, Tuple{Int64, Int64, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, true}}:
 [9 5 4; 8 2 6; 5 7 5]  [5 8 5; 1 6 1; 1 5 5]   [4 10 4; 4 3 10; 4 7 10]  [1 10 5; 9 2 5; 7 1 10]
 [2 7 1; 9 5 3; 7 1 7]  [2 3 9; 5 7 10; 4 1 4]  [2 1 2; 5 1 1; 1 2 4]     [10 1 3; 8 3 8; 9 10 2]
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering - is there a way to do this without a for loop?

Comment: @SreekarVoleti, you can use a `map` function as, `map( j-> map( i-> x[j,i,:,:], axes(x,2) ), axes(x,1) )`

Answer (score 4):

On Julia 1.9, you want `eachslice`:

```
julia> x = rand(Int8,3,3,2,2)
3×3×2×2 Array{Int8, 4}:
[:, :, 1, 1] =
 127  107   27
  31  -90   95
 -50  -92  117
...

julia> eachslice(x; dims=(3,4))
2×2 Slices{Array{Int8, 4}, Tuple{Colon, Colon, Int64, Int64}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}, Base.OneTo{Int64}}, SubArray{Int8, 2, Array{Int8, 4}, Tuple{Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Int64, Int64}, true}, 2}:
 [127 107 27; 31 -90 95; -50 -92 117]  [-58 7 -16; -77 -110 32; -82 25 -48]
 [-40 13 -43; -63 121 47; 28 -64 57]   [62 -61 19; 117 42 101; 70 -82 -62]

julia> eachslice(x; dims=(1,2))
3×3 Slices{Array{Int8, 4}, Tuple{Int64, Int64, Colon, Colon}, Tuple{Base.OneTo{Int64}, Base.OneTo{Int64}}, SubArray{Int8, 2, Array{Int8, 4}, Tuple{Int64, Int64, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}, Base.Slice{Base.OneTo{Int64}}}, true}, 2}:
 [127 -58; -40 62]  [107 7; 13 -61]     [27 -16; -43 19]
 [31 -77; -63 117]  [-90 -110; 121 42]  [95 32; 47 101]
 [-50 -82; 28 70]   [-92 25; -64 -82]   [117 -48; 57 -62]
```

As noted above, usually it's best to use slices containing the leading dimensions, like `x[:,:,i,j]` produced by `eachslice(x; dims=(3,4))`.

On Julia 1.8 & lower, ideally [Compat.jl#663](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Compat.jl/pull/663) will make this work.